# how to configure email SMTP server in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am newbie with Jenkins.

Where is email server (SMTP server and etc) configuration page? Should I install any plugin?

Best reagards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Jenkins->Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Scroll down to find E-mail notification.
Put your SMTP server details there.

Comment: And how to find out what those smtp server details are exactly?  If using Google apps for business email?

Comment: Not sure about Google apps but for me I went and got the details from IT Dept of our company. Maybe you can ask them?

Comment: So there's no possibility to configure this via cli?

Answer (score 0):

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification
or
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Extended E-mail Notification
if you need extended capabilities
Fill SMTP details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUlUE.jpg)